# DBI::dbConnect() doesn't seem to connect when called with source()

Tags: r, sql-server, odbc, rstudio

Learning to use the `odbc` package, and I just hit a small stumbling block. I have code (below) in a script called `conn_to_db.R.` When I run conn_to_db.R in the console, the connection pops up in RStudio's connections window and I can run queries, etc.

It seems that when I call it in another R script, with `source("conn_to_db.R")`, however, the connection does not occur. The script appears to run (If I ask it to print things, it does). Why doesn't it connect to the SQL server?

**EDIT**
It seems the connection is made but it does not appear in RStudio's connection pane when run with `source()`, whereas it does when I run the same lines through the console.

RStudio info: Version 1.2.5001 
Build 1440 (7b3fe265, 2019-09-18)

```
#conn_to_db.R looks like this

library(odbc)
library(DBI)



#save user and password in a file not on git
source("USER.R")
source("PW.R")


#connect to DB
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                  Driver = "/usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib"
                 , Server = "working_IP_Address"
                 , PWD = PW 
                 , Port = 1433)


cat("recall when done good practice to close connection. 
      \nAlso, sometimes useful to clear the result of a query, e.g. here a query called \`stu\` 
      \n# clear results dbClearResult(stu)
      \n# close connection dbDisconnect(con)")
```

Comment: Are all files in the same directory? Are there any other errors? BTW, though I have only tested on Windows and Linux systems, I've never used title-case arguments to `dbConnect`. While the actual argument names differ between DBMS (well, underlying ODBC drivers), it's always been all-lower-case. Are you certain this works manually on your console?

Comment: It looks like you are connecting to a SQL Server; for that, I would use `DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), driver="...", database="dbname", server="working_IP_Address", port=1433, uid="username", pwd="password")`.

Comment: If you don't need to, you don't need to ... I was just including all of the argument names as expected by the mssql odbc driver.

Comment: I just tried with a similar script, with three lines of code: (1) load the appropriate libraries; (2) connect to the database and store it as `con`; (3) run a query. When I `source` that script from a fresh R instance, I get no output at all (including from the query), but I do have `con` in the environment and subsequent queries work as expected. Are you certain that the connection does not occur? Or is it that you don't see output therefore you suspect that it is not working? (IOW, try a manual query after sourcing that file.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209855/discussion-between-michael-and-r2evans).

Comment: It seems the connection is made but it does not show up in RStudio's "Connections" pane as connected

Comment: That sounds like a bug report for RStudio, https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+connections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end (post chat), the connection is established but does not show in RStudio's "Connections" pane. The object does show in the environment, though, so the connection is live and subsequent queries work as expected.

Comment: It appears this is a feature of `obdc` https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/3193